# How to convert a (binary) .key PGP file to an ASCII-armored file?

Tags: pgp

Is there a way to convert a (binary) `.key` file to an ASCII-armored `.asc` file?

There is a previous post which seems to suggest the file extension don't matter, the file content is the same: [What is the difference b/w .pkr and .key file with respect to PGP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8763685/what-is-the-difference-b-w-pkr-and-key-file-with-respect-to-pgp/22541839#22541839)

Comment: Do you want to do this in code? If no, then the question is probably off-topic.

Answer (score 26):

You can use GnuPG for this. From `man gpg`:

```
   --enarmor
   --dearmor
          Pack or unpack an arbitrary input into/from an OpenPGP ASCII armor.
          This is a GnuPG extension to OpenPGP and in general not very useful.
```

`--enarmor` reads from stdin and outputs the armored version to stdout, `--dearmor` works the other way round. For ASCII armoring a binary keyring, use `gpg --enarmor <file.key >file.asc`.

Although the two files are different, they share the same OpenPGP packets and can be converted in both directions. The ASCII-armored version was created for usage in e-mail and other plain ASCII protocols.